# I am getting this ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my app, I encountered the following error: "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator." This error occurred during a navigation attempt from the LoginScreen to the HomeScreen. Here's the relevant code snippet from LoginScreen:

```
// Inside HandleVerification function
if (UserData.phone === '710 00000' && UserData.password === '123') {
  // Log in the user
  dispatch(loginSuccess(UserData));
  navigation.navigate('Home');
} else {
  // Display an error message for incorrect login
  setErrorMessage('Invalid phone number or password.');
}
```

In my navigation setup, I have an AppNavigator that handles the navigation. The AppNavigator includes a TabNavigator, and I expected the 'Home' screen to be within this navigator. However, it seems that the 'Home' screen is not being recognized as part of the navigation stack, leading to this error.

I've provided the relevant code snippets for reference, including the AppNavigator, TabNavigator, and the LoginScreen where the error originates. Any assistance or guidance on resolving this navigation issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

src\navigation\AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AuthenticationNavigator from './AuthenticationNavigator'; // Import the new AuthenticationNavigator
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'; // Import useSelector to access Redux state

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={isAuthenticated ? 'Main' : 'Authentication'}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Authentication"
          component={AuthenticationNavigator}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={TabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

src\navigation\AuthenticationNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import StartScreen from '../screens/StartScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import AuthpageScreen from '../screens/AuthpageScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen';
import VerificationScreen from '../screens/VerificationScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthenticationNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Start"  >
      <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={StartScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="VerificationScreen" component={VerificationScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthpageScreen" component={AuthpageScreen}  options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AuthenticationNavigator;
```

src\navigation\TabNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import BrowseScreen from '../screens/BrowseScreen';
import VendorScreen from '../screens/VendorScreen';
import OrdersScreen from '../screens/OrdersScreen';
import AccountScreen from '../screens/AccountScreen';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const SafeAreaWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
    {children}
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const BigCircularIcon = ({ iconName, color, size, isCentered, focused }) => {
    const iconStyles = [
      styles.bigCircularIcon,
      {
        backgroundColor: focused ? '#130f40' : '#ecf0f1',
        width: size,
        height: size,
        borderRadius: size / 2,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        zIndex: 1,
        // Add shadow styles based on the platform
        ...(Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? { elevation: 5 } // Android shadow using elevation
          : {
              shadowColor: 'black',
              shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
              shadowOpacity: 0.3,
              shadowRadius: 4,
            }), // iOS shadow using shadow properties
      },
      isCentered && styles.centeredIcon,
    ];
  
    return (
      <View style={iconStyles}>
        <Icon name={iconName} size={size * 0.6} color={focused ? 'white' : '#130f40'} />
      </View>
    );
  };

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => {
          if (route.name === 'Vendor') {
            return (
              <BigCircularIcon
                iconName="store"
                color={color}
                size={size + 30}
                isCentered={true}
                focused={focused}
              />
            );
          } else {
            // Change icons for other tabs here
            let iconComponent;
            switch (route.name) {
              case 'Home':
                iconComponent = <Icon name="home" size={size} color={focused ? '#130f40' : color} />;
                break;
              case 'Browse':
                iconComponent = <Icon name="search" size={size} color={focused ? '#130f40' : color} />;
                break;
              case 'Orders':
                iconComponent = <Icon name="clipboard-list" size={size} color={focused ? '#130f40' : color} />;
                break;
              case 'Account':
                iconComponent = <Icon name="user" size={size} color={focused ? '#130f40' : color} />;
                break;
              default:
                iconComponent = null;
            }
            return iconComponent;
          }
        },
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold' }, // Set the label font weight to 'bold'
      })}
      initialRouteName="Vendor"
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#130f40', // Set the active tab color
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Browse" component={BrowseScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Vendor" component={VendorScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigCircularIcon: {
    // Add your styles for the big circular icon here
  },
  centeredIcon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    transform: [{ translateY: -5 }],
  },
});

export default TabNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the TabNavigator is a nested navigator, so you should navigate in this way:

```js
navigation.navigate('Main', {
  screen: 'Home',
});
```

Reference: [Nested navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)